# Can not get MVC, jqGgrid modal edit, and digitalbush masked input working

Tags: jqgrid

Every thing works that I need so I'm pleased with jqGrid, but still having problems with the masked input. More likely the problem is my lack of understanding.

I'm trying to format the input of the Customer's phone number on the modal editing form. I defined the mask but when I add the line editoptions: {datainit: function (elem) { $(elem).mask("(999) 999-9999"); } it will not open the modal form to add or edit. When I remove the line it will open the form but the email formatter doesn't work then.

I read through Trirand's documentation but maybe I'm still confused about the editing functionality.  If anyone has a sample grid using the masked input that may help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

I also changed the order of loading the scripts without any luck. Could it be the versions of the scripts conflicting?  Anyway, I have included the code and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div  class="page-content">
    <table id="JQGrid1" class="ui-jqgrid" ></table>
    <div id="JQGrid1_pager"></div>
</div>

<link href="~/JqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/JqGrid/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- language pack - MUST be included before the jqGrid javascript -->
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- the jqGrid javascript runtime -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $("#CustomerPhone1").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");        
    });

    $("#JQGrid1").jqGrid({
        url: "/Customers/OnCustomerDataRequested",
        editurl: "/Customers/EditCustomerData",
        mtype: "GET",
        datatype: "json", 
        page: 1,
        jsonReader: { id: "Id" },
        prmNames: { id: "Id" },
        colNames: ["Id", "Last Name", "First Name",
        "Address", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip Code", "Email",  "Phone", "Phone",
    "Ship Address", "Ship Address", "Ship City", "Ship State", "Ship Zip", "Ship Phone", "Ship Name"],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, width: 50, name: "Id", hidden: true },
        { name: "CustomerLastName", editable: true, width: 70, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerFirstName", editable: true, width: 70, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerAdd1", editable: true, width: 110, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerAdd2", editable: true, width: 110, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerCity", editable: true, width: 50, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerState", editable: true, width: 60, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerZip", editable: true, width: 60, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerEmail", editable: true, width: 80, editrules: { required: true, formatter: 'email' }, formoptions: { rowpos: 5, colpos: 2 }, formatter: "email" },

        { name: "CustomerPhone1", editable: true, width: 80, index: "CustomerPhone1", edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true },
            editoptions: {datainit: function (elem) { $(elem).mask("(999) 999-9999"); }
              }, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 1 } },

        { name: "CustomerPhone2", editable: true, width: 80, formoptions: { rowpos: 6, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipAdd1", editable: true, width: 110, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipAdd2", editable: true, width: 110, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 8, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipCity", editable: true, width: 50, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 9, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipState", editable: true, width: 60, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 9, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipZip", editable: true, width: 60, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 10, colpos: 1 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipPhone1", editable: true, width: 80, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 10, colpos: 2 } },
        { name: "CustomerShipName", editable: true, width: 80, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 11, colpos: 1 } },
    ],
    height: "auto",
    caption: "Customers",        
    rowNum: 25,
    autowidth: true,
    pager: "#JQGrid1_pager",
}).jqGrid('navGrid', "#JQGrid1_pager", { edit: true, add: true, del: true, view: false, refresh: true },
     { // edit options
         width: 900, height: 595,
         addCaption: 'Edit Customer',
         beforeShowForm: function (form) {                  
             $("#pData, #nData", form).hide();
         },
         closeAfterEdit: true,
     },
    { // add options
        width: 900, height: 595,
        addCaption: 'New Customer',
        beforeShowForm: function (form) {
          //  $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
            $("#pData, #nData", form).hide();
        },            
        closeAfterAdd: false,
        afterSubmit: function (data, postdata, oper) {
            var response = data.responseJSON;
            if (response.hasOwnProperty("error")) {
                if (response.error.length) {
                    return [false, response.error];
                }
            }
            return [true, "", ""];
        },
        errorTextFormat: function (data) {
            return data.responseText
        }
    },

{ // del options
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
editoptions: {dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).mask("(999) 999-9999"); }}
```

you should use `editoptions:{dataInit...` instead of `editoptions:{datainit...`

Example: http://codepen.io/paulodiogo/pen/xGjdJq

Reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules

Comment: Thanks for for catching the capital I in dataInit, I had stared for hours and did not see it.

Comment: Oops, I hit the enter key too soon!  Thanks for for catching the capital I in dataInit, I had looked at the code for hours and did not see it. However, the original problem still exist.  If I remove the line with the edit options the add/edit form opens but the editing mask obviously does not work. With the line, it will not open the add/edit form. I looked at the example link and my line of code looks just like that one.  Anyway, I'm going to recreate the project with the bare minimum to see if I can "back track" into the problem.  Again, thanks for the help.